# Unable to upload file to AWS S3 using python boto3 and upload_fileobj

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, boto3

I am trying to get a webp image, convert it to jpg and upload it to aws S3 without saving the file to disk (using `io.BytesIO` and boto3 `upload_fileobj`) , but with no success. The funny thing is that it works fine if I save the file to local disk and than use boto3 `upload` melhod.

This works:

```
r = requests.get(url)
 if r.status_code == 200:
  file_name = "name.jpeg"
  s3 = boto3.client("s3")
  webp_file = io.BytesIO(r.content)
  im = Image.open(webp_file).convert("RGB")
  im.save(
    f"{config.app_settings.image_tmp_dir}/{file_name}", "JPEG"
  )
  s3.upload_file(
    f"{config.app_settings.image_tmp_dir}/{file_name}",
    config.app_settings.image_S3_bucket,
    file_name,
    ExtraArgs={"ContentType": "image/jpeg"},
  )
```

This does not work:

```
r = requests.get(url)
 if r.status_code == 200:
  file_name = "name.jpeg"
  s3 = boto3.client("s3")
  webp_file = io.BytesIO(r.content)
  im = Image.open(webp_file).convert("RGB")
  jpg_file = io.BytesIO()
  im.save(
    jpg_file, "JPEG"
  )
  s3.upload_fileobj(
    jpg_file,
    config.app_settings.image_S3_bucket,
    file_name,
    ExtraArgs={"ContentType": "image/jpeg"},
  )
```

I can see that the `jpg_file` has the correct size after `im.save`, but when the file is uploaded to aws S3 I get empty file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After calling `im.save(jpg_file, "JPEG")`, the [stream's position](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.tell) is still pointing **after** the newly-written image data. Anything that tries to read from `jpg_file`, will start reading from that position and will *not* see the image data.

You can use the stream's [seek()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek) method to move the position back to the start of the stream, before `s3.upload_fileobj()` tries to read it:

```py
  im.save(
    jpg_file, "JPEG"
  )

  # Reset the stream position back to the start of the stream.
  jpg_file.seek(0)

  s3.upload_fileobj(
    jpg_file,
    config.app_settings.image_S3_bucket,
    file_name,
    ExtraArgs={"ContentType": "image/jpeg"},
  )
```